# Newline in TextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application with a number of text boxes. They have a static width and `TextWrapping` is set to `TextWrapping.Wrap`.

Everything is working great, but sometimes when a user types a text the textbox doesn't re-size. It looks like he thinks it's fitting in the one line but the cursor goes to the newline and when I type one more letter the text box re-sizes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the multiline textbox property set?

Comment: I have AcceptsReturn set to True

Comment: what happens if you set a maxheight on the textbox? ...and which version of SL are you using?

Comment: Silverlight 5 and tested with maxheight but same behavior

Comment: It's inside an grid with rowdefinitions and columndefinitions

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't worked with SL. Does [`WrapWithOverflow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textwrapping.aspx) help?

Comment: Silverlight hasn't got WrapWithOverflow :(

Comment: If you delete the character that makes it resize, does it shrink back to one line again?

Answer (score 0):

It might have related with ScrollBar visibilities. ScrollBar style in the TextBox style might need a fix if you change anything ?